# Ubuntu 16.04 Ethernet Help

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ethernet

So, I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 (Server). And I am having issues getting it connected to the internet on my router.

`ifconfig -a`:

```
enp8s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:**
         inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
         UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
         Interrupt:19

lo       Link encap: Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
         inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
         RX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:196 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
         RX bytes:15016 (15.0 KB)  TX bytes:15016 (15.0 KB)
```

as for when I `ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

last but not least, the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo enp8s0
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**EDIT:**
`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway       Genmask             Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1   0.0.0.0             UG    0      0        0 enp8s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0       U     0      0        0 enp8s0
```

`ip route show`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp8s0 onlink linkdown
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp8s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.7 linkdown
```

`networking.service`:

```
networking.service - Raise network interfaces
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-05-02 21:00:58 EDT; 10min ago
```

(if you need any more of the networking.service just comment saying so)

`ethtool enp8s0`:

```
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                       drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
Link detected: no
```

`ethtool -i enp8s0`:

```
driver: tg3
version: 3.137
firmware-version: sb
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:08:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

`ip neigh show`:

```
192.168.1.1 dev enp8s0  INCOMPLETE
```

Please be detailed with your answers, thank you in advance! :)

Comment: i looked around and found this command `sudo ip link set enp8s0 up` tried testing it on my VM but I can't get a response from `ip route show` to see if when i use the down command it put me in linkdown state. I don't want to do it on my server because  .. well I'm lazy and if I took it down  I would have to actually go over to it to bring it back up :D lol

Comment: `sudo ip link set enp8s0 up` doesn't give me any response. But `ip route show` is in the post. :P

Comment: I'm going to bed now, I will come back to this post tomorrow :) Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: ok when you check again tomorrow .. look and see if it still shows linkdown in your ip route show ... if it doesn't you may have access .. if it does .. try the command again even though it doesn't show a response then run ip route show again and see if it changes from linkdown to not showing linkdown anymore

Comment: Check my reply - updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simply just faulty wiring.

Sorry guys!

Comment: That's funny but expected result ;-D

Answer (score 0):

Pinging 8.8.8.8 it's ICMP, DNS is not involved (but you still need it set properly ;-)

"Destination host unreachable", it's [ICMP control message type 3 code 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), most likely there is not route to to the target host.

So the first thing is to check your routing table

```
route -n
ip route show
```

Get the output.

Try to ping your gateway first and see if that works in the first place.

Check the status of `networking.service`

```
systemctl status networking.service
```

BTW: `iptables` may not be playing a part yet but it'll be good if you can also post the `iptables-save` output.

**Update**

Based on the ethtool output, there is layer 2 issue.

```
Speed: Unknown!
Duplex: Unknown! (255)
```

A few things to point out

1. NIC should support 1000Mbps but has been set to 100Mbps (you did it?)
2. Switch/Router advertised 1000Mbps
3. both sides autoneg is on

   ```
   Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                           100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                           100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
   Supported pause frame use: No
   Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
   Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                           100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                           1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
   ```

Try to set NIC speed to 1000Mbps by `ethtool -s <inferface> speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on`, `ifconfig down` / `ifconfig up` the interface,  and check `ethtool <interface>` again for the Speed and `Link detected` value.

Comment: I added the stuff you asked for, except iptables. iptables-save doesn't return anything. :\

Comment: @Swedz did you ping your gateway 192.168.1.1 from the .7?

Comment: Same error, Destination Host Unreachable.

Comment: `arping 192.168.1.1`, `ethtool enp8s0`, `ethtool -i enp8s0` output? I'd check the cabling.

Comment: I don't have arping because I can't download it due to not having internet connection

Comment: @Swedz at least you should be able to run `arp -n` or `ip neigh show`

Comment: Doing `ethtool -s speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on` gives the error `ethtool: bad command line argument(s)`. As for `ip neigh show`, I will put that in the post now.

Comment: @Swedz `ethtool -s enp8s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on`, missed the interface part.

Comment: I got no response from that command. Still can't ping IP's, can't install packages and can't ping any other PCs on the network it should be on.. **EDIT:** *Speed still says Unknown*

Comment: @Swedz are you sure that cable connect to your router/switch works with a different PC? This can rule out cable to router/switch.

Comment: @Swedz also run `modinfo tg3` and see what kernel module (driver) and firmware combination the NIC is using. `firmware-version: sb` <--- look weird to me.

Comment: It works on the PC I'm using right now, @TerryWang. The `modinfo tg3` just puts a bunch of random numbers and letters, what specifically am I looking for there? `firmware-version: sb` is an unknown command.